# My Angular JS code is not working

Tags: angularjs

I wrote some Angular JS code by learning from a tutorial. But in that video tutorial, the code works properly, but my code is not working. My web page is showing a blank page.

The index.html:

```
<div body ng-app="angularTable">

   <div class="all_cat_main" ng-controller="listdata">

      <div class="all_cat" ng-repeat="state in statelist">

         <h2>{{state.Satename}}</h2>

      </div>

   </div>

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/AppJS/AllSate.js"></script>
```

And the **AllSate.js**

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.statelist = []; 
   $.ajax({
     url: "/JobWebApi/getDataForAngularGrid",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     method: 'GET',
     data: '',
   })
   .success(function (response) {
      $scope.statelist = response;
   })
   .error(function (error) {
       alert(error);
   });
});
```

Please someone guide me why the code is not working ?

Comment: I think this is typo 'Satename' instead of 'Statename'  come like this<h2>{{state.Statename}}</h2>

Comment: Another issue I noticed in controller get success response update the code in the response like this $scope.statelist = response.data;

Comment: What is the error you are getting. And use `$http` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: check also in browser console, maybe you will find some useful error message ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove injected $http from Controller and Firstly Load Jquery lib file.(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata', function ($scope) {
$scope.statelist =""; 
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?ICAO=LSZH&username=demo",
dataType: 'jsonp',
method: 'GET',
data: '',
}).success(function (response) { debugger;
$scope.statelist = response.status;
                                $scope.$apply();
})
.error(function (error) {
alert(error);
});
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="angularTable">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="listdata">
  
    <div >

<div >



  <h2>{{statelist.message}}</h2>


</div>


</div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```